# jalert with jquerymobile not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, alert

I want to use jAlert in my jquery mobile project.

Below is my code. Directory structure is perfectly fine.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
 <script src="libs/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="libs/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Core files -->
 <script src="libs/jquery.alerts/jquery.alerts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <link href="libs/jquery.alerts/jquery.alerts.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"            media="screen" />

 <script src="libs/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
```

I am getting following error.

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined "

Am I missing something?

How to use jAlert with jQueryMobile any example?

Comment: it looks like a jAlert problem, not JQM http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/93AaU/ even if you comment jQM link in head, the same error will be thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`$.browser` API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/), `$.browser.msie` will not work with *jQuery 1.9 or later*, unless **[jQuery Migrate Plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/#readme)** is included.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/93AaU/)**

All you need is adding the below in `<head>`.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
```