# simplemodal does not appear after loading dynamic data into a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, simplemodal

I am using [simpelmodal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/) to create dialog in jquery, but now the issue is in one of my html page i am adding 
`li` elements dynamically , and when on a click of a button i try to fire `$("attachment-modal-content").modal()` dialog box doesnt appear until i again tap over a screen or move the screen. as soon as i move the screen it appears.

notable things is that if i dont load any `li` elements in the page , it popups normally.

here is the example page , initially `attachment-modal-content` is set to `display:none`

```
<div>

<a href="#" id="openDialog" />

     <ul id="mylist">
     </ul>
<div id="attachment-modal-content">
        <h3>Attachment</h3>
        <ul class="attachment">
            <li id="imageBtn" class="green"><a href="#"><em><i class="fa fa-camera"></i></em><span>Image</span></a></li>
            <li id="audioBtn" class="red"><a href="#"><em><i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i></em><span>Audio</span></a></li>
            <li id="videoBtn" class="yellow"><a href="#"><em><i class="fa fa-video-camera"></i></em><span>Video</span></a></li>
            <li id="linkBtn" class="blue"><a href="#"><em><i class="fa fa-link"></i></em><span>Link</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="attachList">

        </ul>
    </div>

</div>

</div>
```

button code

```
$("#openDialog").on('click',function(){

  $("#attachment-modal-content").modal();

});
```

once i load the date using `$('#mylist').append('<li><li>')` , dialog wont appear on a first button click , it appears 
when i move the screen.

Comment: you mean `$("#openDialog")`? `#` not `$` or was it a typo?

Comment: It's okay, can you create simple fiddle reproducing the problem?

Comment: dont know how to do it

Comment: which jQM version is being used?

Comment: it doesnt work iwth jquery mobile i guess `http://jsfiddle.net/szjhu/6/`

Comment: it's working http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/8X3Pt/ make sure you use jQuery 1.8.3 as it doesn't work with 1.9.x. and here's your demo http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/szjhu/10/

Comment: aah.. i am using `1.9` in my whole project , any workaround ?

Comment: you need jquery migrate. check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18531810/1771795 working now http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/szjhu/14/